# android studio with git actions / android No matching configuration of project

Tags: android, git, github-actions, action

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :commModule.
> Required by:
> project :app
> project :app > project :qrModule
> > No matching configuration of project :commModule was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.2', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
> - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

How can i do..?